# Date string with zone info (QTimeZone) to QDateTime and reverse

Tags: python, pyqt6, qdatetime

I want to use PyQt6 with QDateTime. Here's the problem. The first entry is ok. But turning the TEST switch to 1 or 2 will cause various errors. In particular, dealing with the time zones. I know that the QTimeZone has other time zones, but how do I convert them? I want the original string "20230329 15:40:00 US/Eastern" to be the same as the generated, a solution should using QDateTime and QTimeZone.

```
import re
from PyQt6.QtCore import QDateTime, Qt, QTimeZone, QByteArray

PATT_TIME_BASE = re.compile(r"\d{8} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w+(/\w+)?")

for date_str in ["Wed Mar 26 22:37:40 2019 GMT-08","20230329 15:40:00 US/Eastern"]:

    if PATT_TIME_BASE.match(date_str):
        s = date_str.rsplit(" ", 1)
        date_object = QDateTime.fromString(s[0],"yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
        # ---------
        print("List:",s)
        TEST = 0
        if TEST == 1:  # Error (1) : This doesn't work
            qzt = QTimeZone(QByteArray(s[1])) # -> Not Ok
            date_object.setTimeZone(qzt)
            date_str_2 = date_object.toString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss Z")
        if TEST == 2:  # Error (2): This doesn't work
            date_object.setTimeZone(s[1])
            date_str_2 = date_object.toString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss Z")
        else:
            date_str_2 = date_object.toString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")
        #
        print("(2) ",date_str, " -  ", date_object, " - ", date_str_2)
    else:
        date_object = QDateTime.fromString(date_str)
        date_str_2  = date_object.toString()
        #
        print("(1) ",date_str, " -  ", date_object, " - ", date_str_2)
```

What can I do?

Comment: "will cause various errors" -> **what** errors? Are you referring to `argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'`? That's because you cannot create a QByteArray from a basic string, either you provide a byte object, or use `str.encode()`. Then, the 'Z' expression does not indicate the time zone, but whether the time is UTC or none (with the "Z" standing for ["Zulu time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)).

Comment: Please [edit] your post and share which errors you got. What were you expecting instead? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

QByteArray does not accept simple strings as argument, a `bytes` object must be provided.

Also, the `Z` expression in the QDateTime format is not used for the time zone, but to show whether the time is UTC ([Zulu time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Time_zones)). If you want to display the time zone, you need to get its [`id()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtimezone.html#id) and append it to the string.

```py
    qzt = QTimeZone(QByteArray(s[1].encode('utf8')))
    date_object.setTimeZone(qzt)
    date_str_2 = date_object.toString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss ")
    date_str_2 += qzt.id().data().decode('utf8')
```